# Is there a method to divide single insert query to multiple rows in BigQuery using Node.js?

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery

I wanted to insert multiple rows at once into BigQuery using node.js + BQ Client API, it is working like a charm but there's one issue, rows are being added "all in one", it means that single row in BigQuery contains data from actual two (or more) rows. I was trying to build a custom SQL query but managing all repeated fields is terrible. I am retrieving my data from 3rd party REST API.

Is there any better solution to divide all rows into single ones?

```
await bigquery
    .dataset("datasetName")
    .table("tableName")
    .insert(testRows,{'raw':false, 'ignoreUnknownValues':false}, (err, apiResponse) => {
        serverRes.send(`${err} ; Response: ${JSON.stringify(apiResponse)}`);
    });
```

Comment: Are you creating the table with Node.js and then inserting the data ? Have you specified the table schema for the insertion? According to the [documentation](https://googleapis.dev/nodejs/bigquery/latest/Table.html#insert), there is a property, _schema_, inside the `insert()` method where you specify it.

Comment: How are you creating `testRows`?

Comment: @AlexandreMoraes Table was created earlier using payload retrieved from external REST api. I am not including schema while insertion.

@guillaumeblaquiere I've changed a bit my code, it is working as expected but solution is terrible in my opinion. My rows are just a pure payload from external api retrieved using `fetch()` then I am iterating through them using `.map()` and then `BigQuery.insert({"deals":[mapIterationValue},{'raw':false, 'ignoreUnknownValues':true, 'skipInvalidRows': true})`

Comment: @MichalJ, I know you got it working adding some flags to the `insert()` mehotd. However, I would like to suggest to you to export the data to a file, upload it to BigQuery and analyse the differences with the data you were able to upload properly directly from the rest API. Thus, you would be sure that you are not skipping any important payload data.

Comment: The most important question is, if I export data to a file, will it be divided into separate rows? @AlexandreMoraes

Comment: @MichalJ, I am asking you to try that to check how the output looks like. In a way, we can identify errors in the file or it it is needed some formatting before loading to bigquery. You can select a format of your choice such as json. I would like to point that, having 2 rows inside a single row in BigQuery might configure some file error.